# switching Usercontrols and navbar loses data

Tags: c#, templates, mvvm, user-controls, datatemplate

I have a question with a project using MVC.

I have an `UserControl` where I have a `TabControl` with `TabItem`s (they have also `UserControl`s).

The problem is, when I fill in a field and I go to another `TabItem`, the text disappears. I have a model `DOssierModel`, a view-model `UCDossier`, and the views.

Can anyone help me?

I have used a binding:

```
Text="{Binding SelectedOrder.Nummer, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Model:

```
public class DossierModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int IDossierNummer;
    public int Nummer
    {
        get
        {
            return IDossierNummer;
        }
        set
        {
            if (IDossierNummer == value)
                return;
            IDossierNummer = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Nummer);
        }
    }
```

So I fill my `dossiernumber` in and I go to the other `UserControl`; when I return, the data is gone.

View-model:

```
private DossierModel _dossierM;
public DossierModel SelectedOrder
{
    get
    {
        return _dossierM ?? (_dossierM = new DossierModel());
    }
    set
    {
        if (_dossierM == value)
            return;

        _dossierM = value;
    }
}

public DossierViewModel()
{
    SelectedOrder = new DossierModel();
}
```

EDIT

In tab 1 is an devexpress navbar and in tab 2 is an view with the usercontrols. When i select an item from the navbar it opens the usercontrol in tab2. The problem is when i switch between usercontrols , the filled in data is gone.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Set a break point on the property setter and check whether the value is being transferred by the `Binding`. Check for any binding errors in the Output window too.

Comment: I have done that and i see that it changes to the number end when i go to antoher usercontrol it changes back to 0.

Comment: I have solved a part of the problem. When you go from tab 1 to tab 2. The data is kept when you open it. But in tab 1 is an dockpanel and when i select an items it opens in tab 2 . When i switch between them the data is gone. I know it has something to do with virtualisation and cache.